# SQL rows by category convert to column headers

Tags: sql, odbc

Need to turn TBL1 into TBL2 with SQL.

**TBL1**:

```
     Type SubType Value
     ---- ------- -----
     100  100     A
     100  200     B 
     200  100     A
     200  200     C
     300  100     A
     300  300     D
     400  100     A
     400  300     E
```

**TBL2**:

```
     Type v100 v200 V300
     ---- ---- ---- ----
     100   A    B
     200   A    C
     300   A        D
     400   A        E
```

How can I get a new table with the distinct Type in each row all the Subtype as column headers and the Value of the subtype which belongs to the Type.

I am using Excel and ODBC to send a query string to DB2 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without knowing which platform you are discussing SQL-Server, Oracle, mysql, etc.?  The only answer that I can give you is `Conditional Aggregation`:

```
SELECT
    Type
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN SubType = 100 THEN Value END) as v100
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN SubType = 200 THEN Value END) as v200
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN SubType = 300 THEN Value END) as v300
FROM
    Tbl1
GROUP BY
    Type
```

Comment: I am using Excel and ODBC to send a query string to DB2 server.

Answer (score 2):

You  could use a self join

```
 select t1.Type,  t1.Value as v100,  t2.Value as v200,  t3.Value as v300
 from my_table as t1
 left join my_table as t2 on t1.Type = T2.Type and T2.SubType = 200
 left join my_table as t3 on t1.Type = T3.Type and T3.SubType = 300     
 where t1.Subtype = 100
```

Comment: You could do it via joins, though thinking conditional aggregation would beat it performance wise not sure... But this query will NOT produce the desired results because not every Type has a sub type 200 or 300.  And if for some reason type 100 was ever missing that would be a problem too.  You would need a derived table of distinct t1.type then LEFT JOINS

Comment: @Matt   correct .. yes . is left join  not inner. thank  .. answer  updated ..  .. upvote  for your courtesy and ( the good answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dynamic version of Matt's answer:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    Type' + CHAR(10) +
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT
            '   ,MAX(CASE WHEN SubType = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Subtype) + ' THEN Value END) AS '
                + QUOTENAME('v'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SubType)) + CHAR(10)
        FROM Tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, '') +
'FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Type;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

*This is for SQL-Server*

Comment: I am using Excel and ODBC to send a query string to DB2 server